# Ubuntu is not shutting down properly, instead it keeps showing the following after clicking power off

Tags: hard-drive, shutdown, reboot

```
[10196.9841711 wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 70:97:41:e8:7e:20 by local choice (Reason: 3-DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[10197.8623311 systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
[10197.865048] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
[10197.8690401 systemd-journald[340]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdown). 
[10197.9188161 systemd-shutdown [11: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[10197.9230581 systemd-shutdown [1]: Unmounting file systems. 
[10197.923658] [265411: Remounting read-only in with options 'errors-remount-ro'.
[10198.0407771 EXT4-fs (mune@nip2): re-mounted bb93f3c0-ce3e-4768-b4ec-82f93164b49a 
[10198.098045] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[10198.0980981 systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
[10198.8981851 systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated. 
[10198.0982101 systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
[10198.1002291 systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached. [10198.1002591 systemd-shutdown[1]: Stopping MD devices.
[10198.1003181 systemd-shutdown[1]: All MD devices stopped.
[10198.1003421 systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices. 
[10198.1003921 systemd-shutdown[1]: All DM devices detached.
[10198.100418] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems, snaps, loop devices, MD devices and DM devices detached.
[10198.1197891 systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices. 
[10198.120144] systemd-shutdown[1]: Rebooting.
[10198.120226] kvm: exiting hardware virtualization
```

Comment: I have also this problem. After software update, I cannot restart or shutdown the laptop normally. I get this message: "kvm: exiting hardware virtualization"

Comment: @AliN11 do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: In the boot screen, I choose older kernels (5.9) every time